# Convert to base64 captured image in QML

Tags: qt, camera, qml

I'm trying to save as *base64* a captured image in **QML**. This is part of the code. I need to have it in a *variable*.

```
        Camera {            
        id: camera
        videoRecorder {
            frameRate: 30
        }
        imageCapture {              
            onImageCaptured: {
                foto.source = preview                   
            }
            onImageSaved: {
                var imgPath = camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath;
                

                t.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose I have to do it in **onImageSaved**, I've tried:

```
camera.imageCapture.toBase64()
```

And:

```
imgPath.toDataURL(mimeType)
```

But I'm not sure if it's possible ot what I'm doing wrong if it is.

Comment: So what is the problem? Actually , if you want to convert the captured image to Base64 you have to write some C++ extension that does that.

Comment: @folibis The problem is I can't convert it to base64; I only have access to what you see in the code attached basically. I can only touch the QML code - I've already found solutions with C++.

Comment: `imageCaptured` handler provides the image data as is. So you just need to convert that to `Base64` using `Qt.btoa`

Comment: If I do Qt.btoa(camera.imageCapture), I get QDeclarativeCameraCapture(0x49537200etcetc)

Comment: `imageCapture` is object which is absolutely irrelevant here, you have to use the [imageCaptured](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtmultimedia-imagecapture.html#imageCaptured-signal) signal. if you call to `capture()` then the handler will be called.

Comment: @1x2x3x4x all qml types are implemented in c++.by sending path of image after capturing to your c++ class using QFile read bytes and using QByteArry.toBase64 you can convert to Base64

Comment: @1x2x3x4x seems to be that you are doing a lot of coding by trial and error. It will help you to console.log() and check the values and type of everything. You need to get a deeper understanding of the types of things along the way. My original answer should have sufficed, but, I have revised it, in my opinion, beyond what would have been ordinarily necessary for anyone to achieve success.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're restricting the solution to QML, your choices are severely limited. I would really question that since it leads to this solution, which is inefficient because it requires you to save the image first and then load the saved image.

You must:

- Initiate a save by calling `camera.imageCapture.capture()` or equivalent
- Wait for the camera.imageCapture.onImageSaved signal
- This tells you that the image has been encoded and saved to a JPEG file
- You then can load the JPEG into memory as a binary ArrayBuffer object using `XMLHttpRequest`
- Then, you can use `Qt.btoa` on it to get a base64 string from it

The steps are precisely written above to avoid any mistakes or misunderstandings. It's inefficient, since, if you had access to C++ we could consider processing the raw QImage in-memory and do in-memory conversions to an image format of our choosing as well as an in-memory conversion to base64.

```
    Camera {
        id: camera
        imageCapture {
            onImageSaved: {
                let filePath = camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath;
                console.log(filePath); // C:/Users/stephenquan/Pictures/IMG_00000007.jpg
                let fileUrl = Qt.platform.os === 'windows'
                     ? 'file:///' + filePath
                     : 'file://' + filePath;
                 console.log(fileUrl); // file:///C:/Users/stephenquan/Pictures/IMG_00000007.jpg
                 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 xhr.open("GET", fileUrl, false);
                 xhr.send();
                 // //XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
                 let base64 = Qt.btoa(xhr.response);
                 console.log(base64); // final base64 representation of the JPEG image
                 let datauri = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64;
                 console.log(datauri); // a properly formatted datauri for the JPEG image
            }
        }
    }
```

After it is saved, we need to convert that filePath to a fileUrl.

For me, as I'm running it on windows, I can add a `file:///` prefix to turn it into a URL. For other platforms, the prefix is typically `file://`.

Then we can use `Qt.btoa` with `XMLHttpRequest` we can generate the `base64` string for that URL.

See the warning about using XMLHttpRequest on local files.

Below is some refactored black box functions to make all this code reusable for other scenarios.

```js
function urlToBase64(url) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send();
    return Qt.btoa(xhr.response);
}

function fileToBase64(filePath) {
    //XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
    return urlToBase64(Qt.resolvedUrl("file:///" + filePath));
}

function test() {
    let url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    console.log(urlToBase64(fileUrl));
    let filePath = "C:/temp/hello.txt";
    console.log(fileToBase64(filePath));
}
```

[Edit: Additional answer about Canvas.toDataURL]

Alternatively, you can use Canvas.toDataURL but it requires you to load your graphic into the a Canvas object first and then render it once you are sure it's loaded.

[Edit: Additional answer about asynchronous]

There was a comment earlier regarding the proper usage of `XMLHttpRequest`. Because the use case was for local files, I used `XMLHttpRequest.open` with async mode set to `false` to force it to work in synchronous mode.

If you want an asynchronous version of the solution and use it generically for HTTP URLs, I would choose to use Promise chaining as per below.

```js
function asyncUrlToBinary(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
                if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                   reject(new Error(`HTTP Status Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`));
                   return;
                }
                resolve(xhr.response);
            }
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.send();
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    } );
}

function asyncBtoA(data) {
    return Promise.resolve(Qt.btoa(data));
}

function asyncTest() {
    let url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    asyncUrlToBinary(url)
    .then(data => asyncBtoA(data))
    .then(base64 => console.log(base64))
    .catch(err => { console.error(err.fileName + ":" + err.lineNumber, err.message); throw err; } )
    ;
}
```

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#btoa-method
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#resolvedUrl-method
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-canvas.html